# ¿Como inserto elementos a una pila con un vector?

Tags: c++

Dado un vector de 20 posiciones (números enteros). Genere un programa que
permita realizar las siguientes operaciones.

- Ingresar un elemento en la última posición de la pila (primera posición libre
  del vector), comprobando antes del ingreso que existe una posición libre,
  sino colocar un mensaje de aviso.
- Sacar el elemento que se encuentra en la última posición (si hay, sino
  colocar un mensaje de aviso).
- Listar en cualquier momento el contenido de la pila del primero al último.

Esa es la consigna del trabajo, el 3er punto es relativamente facil, el segundo
mas o menos, pero el primero no se que hacer, probe de todo y siempre el
programa termina rompiendo dandole un valor a i muy elevado

```
using namespace std;

struct Nodo
{
    int dato;
    Nodo *siguiente;
};

void agregarPila(Nodo *&pila, int n)
{
    Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo;
    nuevo_nodo->dato = n;
    nuevo_nodo->siguiente = pila;
    pila = nuevo_nodo;
}

void sacarPila(Nodo *&pila, int &n)
{
    Nodo *aux = pila;
    n = aux->dato;
    pila = aux->siguiente;
    delete aux;
}


int main()
{
    int opcion = NULL;
    Nodo *pila = NULL;
    int vec[4];
    cout << "Ingrese '0' para ver el menu de opciones" << endl;
    cin >> opcion;
    while (opcion != 4)
    {
        int i=0;
        cout << vec[4];
        if (opcion == 0)
        {
            cout << "\n(1) Agregar valor a la pila" << endl;
            cout << "(2) Sacar valor de la pila" << endl;
            cout << "(3) Listar elementos de la pila" << endl;
            cout << "(4) Finalizar el programa" << endl;
            cin >> opcion;
        }
        if (opcion == 1)
        {
            if (vec[4] == 0)
            {
                cout << "\nIngrese el valor a agregar: ";
                cout << i;
                cin >> vec[i];
                agregarPila(pila, vec);
                i++;
                cout << i;
                opcion = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "\nLa pila esta llena" << endl;
                opcion = 0;
            }
        }
        if (opcion == 2)
        {
            if(vec[0] != 0)
            {
                sacarPila(pila, vec);
            }

        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Leyendo muy por encima veo que declaras un array de 4 elemento `int vec[4]`. Esto quiere decir que los índices del array van del 0 al 3, así que cuando luego buscas el último elemento haciendo `if (vec[4] == 0)`y similares, recuerda que estás fuera de rango. El último elemento es `vec[3]`

Comment: Hola, estas seguro? int vec[4] Es, si no me equivoco de 0 a 4, son 5 elementos

Comment: Si. Ese es un error muy común al principio. Mira este enlace: https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: Sigo teniendo el problema igual, no se porque el valor de "i" Se pone re loco, literalmente se rompe y me da un numero aleatorio cualquiera